# Fourier transform of a function of absolute values

Tags: fourier-analysis, complex-numbers, contour-integration

I need help in computing the Fourier transform of

$$\frac{1}{1+|x|^2}$$

with $x$ scalar. I tried using Cauchy integral formula with contours centred around the origin but I get stacked.

Comment: The absolute value is not needed. But you're right: a semicircular contour in the upper half plane will be fine.

Comment: I'm not sure how Cauchy's integral formula would be able to help you in this case.

The function $\operatorname{f}(z) := \frac{1}{1+|z|^2}$ has no poles since $1+|z|^2 \ge 1$ for all $z \in \mathbb{C}$. Moreover, $\operatorname{f}$ *is not* holomorphic; the Cauchy-Riemann equations hold if and only if $z=0$.

Comment: @FlybyNight: read Cameron's comment; he doesn't need the absolute value in the first place.  Then the analysis is standard residue theory.

Answer (score 2):

Let $f(x) = \frac{1}{1+x^{2}}$. The definition of the Fourier transform I consider is the following :

$$ 
\begin{eqnarray*}
\hat{f}(\xi) & = & \int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x) e^{-2i \pi x \xi} \: dx \\
& = & \int_{\mathbb{R}} \frac{1}{1+x^{2}} e^{-2i \pi x \xi} \: dx
\end{eqnarray*} $$

for $\xi \in \mathbb{R}$. One idea is to use the residue theorem (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_theorem). Let be $\xi \in \mathbb{R}$ fixed, you can consider the function

$$ \phi_{\xi}(z) = \frac{1}{1+z^{2}} e^{-2i\pi z \xi}, \, z \in \mathbb{C} $$

$\phi_{\xi}$ is a meromorphic function which has simple poles at $z=i$ and $z=-i$. Use the contour which illustrates the Wikipedia page. The example on the Wikipedia page is almost the same as here.

Comment: @ameronWilliams. Thanks. That is a starting point. The reason why I need the absolute value is because I am trying to generalise to the Fourier Transform of functions of norms. In this particular case $x\in R^n$ and I would want to transform $\frac{1}{1+\lVert{x}\rVert^2}$.

Answer (score 0):

With x being scalar, there is no need of taking absolute value since x is squared. And for taking fourier transform you can just apply duality property of fourier transform as :

```
            Ff(-s) = invFf(s) ; where invF is inverse Fourier transform.
```

Now we know that fourier transform of exp(-a|x|) is 2*a/(a^2 + (2*pi*x)^2) . From this the solution is straight forward that fourier transform of 1/(1 + x^2) would be :

```
                                  pi*exp(-|2*pi*f|)
```

note : exp(-a*|x|) is even function of x.

Comment: You can actually derive the Duality property yourself, its not involved !!